# How to interpret ZipInfo.date_time value

Tags: python, datetime, zip

The documentation on [ZipInfo objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipinfo-objects) wasn't really helpful regarding this. What is this `date_time` value? Is it UTC or local machine time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I guess I just found my answer [here](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/zip.html):

> Inside zip files, dates and times are stored in local time in 16 bits, not UTC (Coordinated Universal Time/Temps Universel Coordonné) as is conventional, using an ancient MS DOS format. Bit 0 is the least signifiant bit. The format is little-endian. There was not room in 16 bit to accurately represent time even to the second, so the seconds field contains the seconds divided by two, giving accuracy only to the even second.